# For any two disjoint convex open sets there is a hyperplane that strictly separates them

Tags: convex-analysis

How to prove the affirmation?:

> If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are nonempty, nonintersecting, convex and open sets, there exists a closed hyperplane $M$ such that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are strictly on opposite sides of M.

Exists a version of Hahn-Banach Theorem that said:
Let $A ⊂ E$ and $B ⊂ E$ be
two nonempty convex subsets such that $A ∩B = ∅$. Assume that one of them is open.
Then there exists a closed hyperplane that separates $A$ and $B$. (But not necessary in the sense strictly)

Comment: If $A$ is open and convex, and if it lies in a closed half-space, then it even lies in the open half-space. If you apply this to $A$ and $B$, your desired result follows.

Answer (score 1):

If $F\subset G$, then the interior of $F$ (denoted $\operatorname{int}F$) is contained in $\operatorname{int}G$. As a special case: if $F\subset G$ and $F$ is open, then $F\subset\operatorname{int}G$.  With this in mind, the following comment by [gerw](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547296/nonempty-open-convex-sets-hyperplane#comment3153202_1547296) completes the solution.

> If $A$ is open and convex, and if it lies in a closed half-space, then it even lies in the open half-space. If you apply this to $A$ and $B$, your desired result follows.